# Printing Multiple PDFs from Java as a single print job (physical printing)

Tags: java, pdf, printing

I would like to print multiple pdfs from java (using the java print service) in a single print job.

I would like to send multiple pdfs as a single job to the printer. This is so that all the documents in my 'batch' print together and are not interleaved with someone else's print jobs when I go pick them up from the printer.

A batch potentially consists of 1000s of print jobs.

I tried jpedal, but it does not support java.awt.print.Book

```
        Book book = new Book();
        PdfDecoder pdfDecoder = readFileApplyOptions("C:/Temp/singlepagetest.pdf", pageFormat);
        book.append(pdfDecoder, pageFormat);

        PdfDecoder pdfDecoderTwo = readFileApplyOptions("C:/Temp/printfax-test.pdf",pageFormat);
        book.append(pdfDecoderTwo, pageFormat);

        printJob.setPageable(book);
        printJob.print();
```

only prints out the first pdf. How do I print multiple pdfs in a single job?

readFileAndApplyOptions() basically creates a new PdfDecoder object and returns it.

I also tried Sun's PDFRenderer [PDFRenderer](https://pdf-renderer.dev.java.net/) in a similar fashion (using the Book object), but my code still only prints out the first page only.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Is there a solution I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Not Java specific, but I've experience of this one in C#.  I solved it by printing each document to a file (programmatically equivalent to checking the "PrintToFile" checkbox on a print dialog), then concatenated each file into a memory stream, which I passed to the Win32 API printer spool in raw format (since the output to file was already correctly formatted by default).

You might be able to use a similar technique in Java

Answer (score 2):

I met the same difficulties when printing at once several JPanels of a JTabbedPane, each on a separate page. I gather them in a Book but it only prints the first page.

The Book class works well (right number of pages), but I suppose the problem comes from setPageable. Since a Book is not a Printable, I made it, and it works !

Workaround:

1. Design a PrintableBook class : extends Book, implements Printable

   ```
   public class PrintableBook extends Book implements Printable {
       Vector<Printable> pages;// NB: we assume pages are single

       public PrintableBook() {
           super();
           pages = new Vector<Printable>();
       }

       public void add(Printable pp) {
           append(pp, pp.getPageFormat());
           pages.add(pp);
       }

       public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
           if (pageIndex >= pages.size())
               return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
           else {
               Printable pp = pages.elementAt(pageIndex);
               return pp.print(g, pf, 0);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then use `printJob.setPrintable( printableBook )` instead of `setPageable`

Comment: Nice workaround! But, I don't think, problem lies in `setPageable()` method. Also, you don't have to use a separate `Vector` for pages, as `Book` internally does that. So, use `getNumberOfPages()` instead of `pages.size()` and `getPrintable(pageIndex)` instead of `pages.elementAt(pageIndex)` calls.

Answer (score 1):

You should merge all of your pdf documents in one document using [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) library and then print the merged document page by page.

see [Print a PDF Document in Java](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2008/01/17/print-a-pdf-document-in-java/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't, multiple documents will be printed in multiple jobs.

A workaround could be join all the pdf into a single document and print them.

:-/