# Setting page break in JEditorPane HTML for printer

Tags: java, swing, printing, jeditorpane

I have a simple report printing routine that spits data into a java JEditorPane (HTML) using tables and then I use either

```
DocumentRenderer dr = new DocumentRenderer();
dr.print(jEditorPane1);
```

(DocumentRenderer found at tek-tips-dot-com) or...

```
try {
    jEditorPane1.print(new MessageFormat("My text pane header"), 
            new MessageFormat("Footer. Page - {0}"), true, null, null, true);
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            //
    }
}
```

(I'm experimenting with both at the moment).

What I would like to do is add a page break after each table so that they each print on separate pages. (Or at least start printing on new pages).

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Use a extended printable book:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4256155/2382406

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JTable instead, there is print support.  Page breaks happen automatically if the table is too large.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. True, but what I need to do is force a page break at a specific location. (The DocumentRenderer works fine and pages break where they should already).

Comment: You may need to use java.awt.Print and the Book class to get this done.  I am currently developing some software that uses these classes so I can give you some sample code if you like.

Comment: Thanks! That would be great. Any help at this point is greatly appreciated.