# Java printing. Prints only one page when using `Book` class

Tags: java, printing

I use [`Book`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/print/Book.html) class to provide different orientation to pages when printing PDF document.

But when I use Book class prints only first page. Other pages doesn't printing. But  `Book#getNumberOfPages` return me `4`.

My code looks like this:

```
   public static getDoc(DocAttributeSet dset) {
        final PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buf);
            Book book = new Book();
            for (int i=0; i<pdfFile.getNumPages(); i++) {
                PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(i);
                PageFormat pageFormat =  new PageFormat();

                if (page.getAspectRatio() >= 1) {
                    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
                } else {
                    pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
                }
                boolean needStop = false;
                if (pdfFile.getNumPages() - 1 == i ) { // if latest page, then stopping ('needStop' = NO_SUCH_PAGE)
                    needStop = true;
                }
                book.append(getPrintable(page, needStop), pageFormat);
            }
          return new SimpleDoc(book, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, dset);
      }    

    private static Printable getPrintable(final PDFPage page, final boolean needStop) {
            return new Printable() {
                public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int index) throws PrinterException {
                    if (needStop) {
                        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                    }

                    // no scaling, center PDF
                    ... // code omitted

                    return PAGE_EXISTS;

                }
            };
    }
```

**Please note**: I'm use this code to print document:

```
DocPrintJob job = prn.createPrintJob();
job.print(myDoc, aset);
```

i.e. I not use old API:

```
Book bk = new Book();       
job.setPageable(bk);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're going to such an extend when you could simply `new SimpleDoc(psStream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);` where `psStream` is an `InputStream` to your PDF file?

Comment: @MadProgrammer because not all printers  have native suupport of PDF format. So I convert PDF file to image and print it as image. I think problem is related with `PAGE_EXISTS` and `NO_SUCH_PAGE`...How I need return `PAGE_EXISTS` and `NO_SUCH_PAGE` when using `Book`? Is my usage right?

Comment: Use a printableBook like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4256155/2382406

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to place the maximum number of pages to print in the "book", maybe 3 or 10 ,that does not mean that it will print all that 10, only mark the size of the book:

```
book.append(getPrintable(page, needStop), pageFormat, numPages);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the test code I put together...

It doesn't print PDF's but test's the change in page orientation and page count.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import javax.print.attribute.DocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashDocAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;

public class TestBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

        HashDocAttributeSet docAttSet = new HashDocAttributeSet();
        Doc myDoc = getDoc(docAttSet);
        PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(psInFormat, aset);

        // this step is necessary because I have several printers configured  
        PrintService myPrinter = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            String svcName = services[i].toString();
            System.out.println("service found: " + svcName);
            if (svcName.contains("DocuCentre-III C3100")) {
                myPrinter = services[i];
                System.out.println("my printer found: " + svcName);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (myPrinter != null) {
            DocPrintJob job = myPrinter.createPrintJob();
            try {
                job.print(myDoc, aset);

            } catch (Exception pe) {
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("no printer services found");
        }
    }

    public static SimpleDoc getDoc(DocAttributeSet dset) {
        Book book = new Book();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
            } else {
                pageFormat.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
            }
            boolean needStop = false;
            if (3 == i) { // 'needStop' = NO_SUCH_PAGE
                needStop = true;
            }
            book.append(getPrintable(i, needStop), pageFormat);
        }
        System.out.println("Book = " + book.getNumberOfPages());
        return new SimpleDoc(book, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PAGEABLE, dset);
    }

    private static Printable getPrintable(int page, boolean needStop) {
        return new MyPage(page, needStop);
    }

    public static class MyPage implements Printable {

        private int page;
        private boolean needStop;

        public MyPage(int page, boolean needStop) {
            this.page = page;
            this.needStop = needStop;
        }

        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int index) throws PrinterException {
            g.translate((int)pageFormat.getImageableX(), (int)pageFormat.getImageableY());
            System.out.println("Printing " + page);
            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 128);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(String.valueOf(index), 0, g.getFontMetrics().getAscent());

//            if (needStop) {
//                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
//            }
            return PAGE_EXISTS;

        }
    }
}
```

From the looks of it, your `needStop` was misplaced.  This should only be called when no more pages actually need to be printed, but the way I read your code (and I could be wrong) it seemed to want to skip the last page.

However, after testing, it would seem you don't actually need it (as the `Book` knows how many pages it wants to print ;))

Comment: Yes, after removing `needStop ` it works with different behavior. Now my first page printed twice and last page don't printed at all...

Comment: Instead of passing the `PDFPage` you could pass it the page index and pull the page directly from the `pdfFile` when it's printed...Also, trying putting in `System.out` to see what page the API is actually trying to print

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `print()` method of `Printable` like this:

```
@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageNumber)
        throws PrinterException {
    if (pageNumber < book.getNumberOfPages()) {
        // Printing code here

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}
```

For this, you must have reference to your `book` instance which can be achieved by making a inner class `Page` implementing `Printable` interface with the above `print()` method definition.